# Dojo Radio button group linedirection?

Tags: xpages

I'm using a Dojo radio button group in a mobile Xpage and it is in page direction, I'd like it to be in line direction. It's a setting for the Xpage Domino radio button group, but I can't find how to do this with the Dojo version.

I have no problem using the Xpage Domino radio button group, but in some mobile orientations the radio button group is cut off part of the way across.

I've been digging into this across several fora and posts, but I've not found anything that does this in mobile Xpages.

Could someone please give me a pointer?

Cheers,
Brian

Comment: The answer in my mind is too easy so I decided I didn't understand what you mean :)
Do you mean creating multiple dojo radio buttons with groupname attributes?

Comment: Yes, Serdar, I'm doing exactly that, I just don't know how to move the orientation of the group.

Comment: Encapsulating all radio tags inside <ul><li></li></ul> lists and format them via CSS would help I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stick with the XPages provided radio button group you can change the direction by setting the direction property on the radioGroup control to either lineDirection or pageDirection.

Comment: Except for them getting cut off, yes. I'm not sure what is causing that. Thanks Per.

Comment: Have a look at the CSS. I'm sure it can be fixed.